# Windows 10 wont boot can i remove and install Linux from command prompt?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I know windows can be replaced by Linux ive seen the questions however they are all from a working machine. Mine is dead it will not reboot startup repair does not work and attempting to Fix Boot from command prompt has also been unsuccessful starting here is it possible to load Linux via USB or otherwise any and all thoughts are appreciated
Thank you

Comment: the question is very unclear. Please [edit] the question and explain what are you trying to do and how is this related to Ubuntu.

Comment: well, you have to make a live USB through any other working system. And If you don't want to use any other system than tell me first how you will get ubuntu's iso first.

Comment: My windows 10 machine will not boot. I have tried resetting using system restore it will not Uninstaller updates and I am at the command prompt for troubleshooting or booting in safe mode, which also isn't working. I would like to attempt to replace windows with Linux but I am unsure how to do it from here,

Comment: Predict exactly what I am asking if I down load from another machine to usb I am unsure how to proceed once that is done

Comment: You can create a LiveUSB on another machine then boot from it and install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I was in this same position that you are in. The easiest thing to do is download the latest Ubuntu LTS ISO and burn it onto a DVD. Boot from the DVD then install. I would stick with the LTS. They are more stable for the most part. Avoid the latest versions until you know what you are doing.

There are some documented installation bugs in the latest LTS. There are also work-arounds for these bugs. You will have Internet access to search online during the install. This was what I did when I encountered errors during install. As an example, choosing third-party drivers during installation resulted in an install error. The work-around was to disconnect your Internet connection/cable during install. After installation completes, reconnect Internet, reboot, and finally update your new install.

Comment: That is what I've done thank you all i realize how silly my question seems now it was so easy once I got a decent usb j gues my first attempt was corrupted once I bought new usb everything fell together thanks all !